# Strange error in FindInstance result

Tags: equation-solving, findinstance

I was running the following code

```
pts = {-0.0002982071829578971`, 0.0020978674014467125`, 0.00454757795374431`, -0.00040056752260654235`, \
   -0.007366648883367612`, 0.007300363592367062`, 0.003436765849222534`, 
   0.001474610688815707`, -0.00604661411313466`, 0.0025407914514535765`};
xs = Cos[pts];
ys = Sin[pts];
fi = FindInstance[{ Cos[t1] + Cos[t2] == 2 Mean[xs],
        Sin[t1] + Sin[t2] == 2 Mean[ys],
        -0.01 <= t1 <= 0.01, -0.01 <= t2 <= 0.01
       }, {t1, t2}, Reals]
```

Mathematica 13.0.1 returns the following result

```
{{t1 -> 1. (1. Root[{{Cos[1. (1. #1^2 - 0.01)] + 
            Cos[1. (1. #3^2 - 0.01)] - 1.9999810103927544 &, 
          Sin[1. (1. #1^2 - 0.01)] + Sin[1. (1. #3^2 - 0.01)] - 
            0.0014571901262632012 &, 1. #1^2 + 1. #2^2 - 0.02 &, 
          1. #3^2 + 1. #4^2 - 0.02 &}, {0.0802012, -0.1164808, 
          0.1225764, -0.0705339}}, 1]^2 - 0.01), 
  t2 -> 1. (1. Root[{{Cos[1. (1. #1^2 - 0.01)] + 
            Cos[1. (1. #3^2 - 0.01)] - 1.9999810103927544 &, 
          Sin[1. (1. #1^2 - 0.01)] + Sin[1. (1. #3^2 - 0.01)] - 
            0.0014571901262632012 &, 1. #1^2 + 1. #2^2 - 0.02 &, 
          1. #3^2 + 1. #4^2 - 0.02 &}, {0.0802012, -0.1164808, 
          0.1225764, -0.0705339}}, 3]^2 - 0.01)}}
```

with the Root[] functions displayed as red boxes with error messages
[image: Mathematica output]

> An unknown box name (ElisionsDump`toNumericalEllipsisedForm) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression. Check the format rules for the expression.

In the meanwhile, it is easy to find solutions to the equations using `FindRoot` as

```
In[127]:= fi = FindRoot[{Cos[t1] + Cos[t2] == 2 Mean[xs],
      Sin[t1] + Sin[t2] == 2 Mean[ys]
    }, {{t1, 0.01/2}, {t2, -0.01/2}}]]

Out[127]= {t1 -> 0.00502497, t2 -> -0.00356777}
```

The values of `t_1` and `t_2` are contained within $[-0.01,0.01]$. `FindInstance` could have found this.

I'd like to ask why FindInstance returns `Root[]` that cannot be evaluated, even numerically. Is this a bug? Is it possible to fix the issue using `FindInstance`? (It is also a bit surprising to me that FindInstance seems to use some symbolic computation internally.)

I am sorry that I do not have a smaller example -- I generated random points in `pts` and ran the code several times before I encountered the problem. I do not know of a pattern of `pts` that would trigger this problem.

Comment: `pts = Rationalize[pts, 0];`

Comment: `NSolve[Rationalize[{Cos[t1] + Cos[t2] == 2 Mean[xs], 
   Sin[t1] + Sin[t2] == 2 Mean[ys], -0.01 <= t1 <= 0.01, -0.01 <= t2 <=
     0.01}, 0], {t1, t2}]`

Comment: I think this is a bug. Please report it to:  support@wolfrom.com

Answer (score 3):

`FindInstance` is symbolic so it work with precise values.

Use `Rationalize[#,0]&`

```
FindInstance[
 Rationalize[{Cos[t1] + Cos[t2] == 2 Mean[xs], 
   Sin[t1] + Sin[t2] == 2 Mean[ys], -0.01 <= t1 <= 0.01, -0.01 <= t2 <=
     0.01}, 0], {t1, t2}, Reals]
```

[image]

Also work in `Solve`.

```
Solve[Rationalize[{Cos[t1] + Cos[t2] == 2 Mean[xs], 
   Sin[t1] + Sin[t2] == 2 Mean[ys], -0.01 <= t1 <= 0.01, -0.01 <= t2 <=
     0.01}, 0], {t1, t2}, Reals]
```

Comment: Thanks! However, it seems to me that rationalizing the expression sometimes causes FindInstance to become slower and return highly complicated expressions for the variables, and in such cases, FindInstance can return the answer very quickly without rationalization. Do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: Your claim "`FindInstance` is symbolic so it work with precise values" does not correspond to reality in view of `FindInstance[Sin[x] == 0.4, x,Reals]` which results in `{{x -> -12.1549}}`.